# MATLAB How to modify property of a value class from a method within a class that is within the original class?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, handle

I would like to create a class that stores, and is able to modify a vector. Looks something like this:

```
classdef vect3d
      properties
            vec
            rotate
      end

      methods
            function obj = vec3d(a,b,c)
                  vec = [a,b,c];
                  rotate = rot(obj) ;
            end
      end
end
```

I have another class that is named rot; which has functions for rotating vectors. What i would like to do is:

```
MyVec = vec3d([1;2;3]);
MyVec2 = MyVec;

% Define a Directional cosine matrix to rotate the vector
MyDCM = ... ;

MyVec.rotate.byDCM(MyDCM) ;
% MyVec should now contain the rotated vector
% MyVec2 should remain as the original vector
```

If i use handle class instead of value class, i can do this manipulation; however if i set another variable equal to MyVec, they become linked (both point to the same object) which is what i want to avoid.

I would like to pass a pointer to my variable to the rot class, so that i can manipulate it within the functions of the rot class.

In short:
I want to be able to use

```
MyVec.rotate.byDCM( MyDCM)
```

to modify MyVec, without actually creating a copy of it in the memory. I want byDCM to be a method within rotate, not that of MyVec. And i would like to be able to safely deep copy my variable.

I hope i explained myself clearly. 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do

```
MyVec = rotate.byDCM(MyVec, MyDCM);
```

The only way to modify a variable passed into a function is if it is a handle class, but then you will not be able to make a deep copy with `MyVec2 = MyVec`.

If the `rotate.byDCM` function is implemented as follows:

```
function vec = byDCM(vec, DCM)
   % modify vec here
```

then MATLAB will optimize things so that `vec` is never copied. Note that in the function definition, the same variable name appears in the input and output list. When calling the function, the same variable (`MyVec`) that is passed as that argument also receives the output. The MATLAB interpreter understands this and allows the function to modify the variable in-place.

Reference: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/

Comment: Thank you. Just as i suspected. Would i be correct in assuming that you can not create a handle version of a value, as if it was a pointer in C; then pass it into the function?

Comment: @Dobacetr: You need to make it a handle class. There is no way to say "this variable should become a handle".